# Android get view ID based on it's tag

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any way to get the ID as in, `findViewById(R.id.tableLayout)`, based on it's XML tag?

For example the Java equivalent of something along these lines: 
`GET $id OF view WHERE 'tag' IS n`

Sorry that looks more like SQL, but I thought it would make my question clearer.

I want to be able to find a view based on it's tag and then convert it to a button using something like this.

`Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);`

Comment: *"based on it's XML tag"*...based on what xml tag, exactly?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Xml tag in `content_main.xml`. `android:tag="0"`

Comment: Why not use the `android:id` like it's meant for?

Comment: Because the app is a small tic tac toe game. It's working by using the tags of the buttons to fill in grids and work out win/lose. Tags I can just use an integer as a string and convert, `android:id` would be more tricksy manipulating strings. If I have to change it I will but I'd prefer a quicker alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use `View#findViewWithTag("someTag")` to reference the view then get the id from the view.

```
View view = findViewWithTag("someTag");
int id = view.getId();
```

Same thing for a button

```
Button b = (Button) findViewWithTag("someTag");
int id = b.getId();
```

references:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()

Edit: If your in an activity (inside `onCreate`) you could get do this

```
// create the Activity's view
View root = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null);
// set the view
setContentView(root);
// find another view by the tag of the root view
Button b = (Button) root.findViewWithTag("someTag");
```

Comment: `findViewWithTag` does not seem to be recognised by Android Studio

Comment: @RichC it is a method of `View`: `View#findViewWithTag`

Comment: Updated answer to show how to get a reference to the root `View` set inside `Activity.onCreate` method

Comment: Could you put a little comment there to say what that does?

Comment: Cheers mate, much appreciated