# How to identify EditText by its tag

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, findviewbyid

I am trying to get the value out of a series of EditText views in my app with a for() loop, but when I call the getText() method, the app crashes. There are 9 EditTexts and they each have a Tag from 1-9, so I am trying to use the getIdentifier() method and search for each EditText using its Tag, and I think that's the part that's not working... Any thoughts here? Thanks in advance!

```
public void xCalculateProfits (View view){
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++){
            EditText xCurrentBox = (EditText) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(Integer.toString(x),"tag",getPackageName()));
            Toast.makeText(this, xCurrentBox.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android get view ID based on it's tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598228/android-get-view-id-based-on-its-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried using that method, but Android Studio didn't recognize it, and so it won't compile...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'r app crashed because xCurrentBox is null.
you can define an int array and in that you store id of each EditText and use for loop to access the all EditText.

of course you can find View with tag . but you must can access to root view.
for example i have a linear layout in my activity and i can use that to access child view by tag .

for example :

```
   LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    for(int i=1 ; i<=4 ; i++)
    {
        EditText et = linearLayout.findViewWithTag(i+"");
        Toast.makeText(this , et.getText().toString() , 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: @JQSOFT I edited answer and added right code in that

Answer (score 1):

To find view by its tag, use `View#findViewWithTag("tag")`. This is a method of a `View` class, so you have to call it on any layout below your EditTexts, for example root View:

```
View root = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++){
    EditText xCurrentBox = (EditText) root.findViewWithTag("" + i);
    Toast.makeText(this, xCurrentBox.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**However**, if you created these EditTexts in layout .xml file (not generated dynamically), I would suggest creating an array containing their IDs, like so:

```
public int[] viewsIds = {
        R.id.edit_text1,
        R.id.edit_text2,
        R.id.edit_text3,
        R.id.edit_text4,
        ...
};
```

and then use it in your for loop

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++){
        EditText xCurrentBox = (EditText) findViewById(viewsIds[i]);
        Toast.makeText(this, xCurrentBox.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This way your code is safer as you can benefit from static typing with autogenerated R class